# Spying on function of object created within Backbone view

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine

I'm trying to spy on a Backbone view. Within one of the view function, an object is created and attached to the view:

```
var BackboneView = Backbone.View.extend({

    anObject: null,

    .....

    viewFunction: function() {

        if (!this.anObject) {
                    this.anObject = new theObject();
                    this.anObject.setTimeout(10);
        }
    }),

    ....
});

return BackboneView;
```

The object looks like this (and cannot be changed):

```
var theObject = function () {

    this.setTimeout = function (timeout) {
        //set timeout
    };

    return this;
});

return theObject;
```

I want to make sure setTimeout was called. So I tried:

```
    it('theObject.prototype.setTimeout called', function () {

        spyOn(theObject.prototype, 'setTimeout');

        myBackboneView.viewFunction()

        expect(theObject.prototype.setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
```

But I get the error:

```
    setTimeout() method does not exist
```

So I try to spy on it through the Backbone view:

```
    it('myBackboneView.anObject.setTimeout called', function () {

        spyOn(myBackboneView.anObject, 'setTimeout');

        myBackboneView.viewFunction();

        expect(myBackboneView.anObject.setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
```

But I predictably get the error:

```
spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for setTimeout()
```

Any ideas how I make sure setTimeout() was called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> setTimeout() method does not exist

Because you did not set setTimeout on the function prototype.

if you want a function on a prototype you need to put it on a prototype,then you can spy on the function.

```
theObject.prototype.setTimeout=function(){/*some code*/}
```

and no need to return this in the constructor.

```
  this.setTimeout = function (timeout) {
        //set timeout
    };

    return this; // this is wrong!!!
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the code being tested cannot change. Will edit question

Comment: what's the purpose of testing if you cant refactor?

Comment: the code isn't written by me but by another programmer and only he refactor, thats how the organisation works

Comment: well that code is not testable so it doesnt really make a difference how your organisation works.If you want to test it make it testable or dont test it.